# How to change the size of button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have three buttons in my login page each of them are a different type of login options when i type in bigger texts in one button that itself is changing how can i keep everything constant.can someone look into it please.

Here's my code:

```
child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlutterLogo(size: 150),
              SizedBox(height: 50),
              _signInButton(),
              _signInFbButton()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _signInButton() {


    return Container(
      child: OutlineButton(
        splashColor: Colors.grey,
        onPressed: () {
          signInWithGoogle().whenComplete(() {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return FirstScreen();
                },
              ),
            );
          });
        },
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
        highlightElevation: 0,
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image(image: AssetImage("Assets/google_logo.png"), height: 35.0),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      'Sign in with Google',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.grey,



  }
  Widget _signInFbButton() {


    return Container(
      child: OutlineButton(
        splashColor: Colors.grey,
        onPressed: () {
          signInWithGoogle().whenComplete(() {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return FirstScreen();
                },
              ),
            );
          });
        },
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
        highlightElevation: 0,
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
        child: Container(
          child: Padding(

            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image(image: AssetImage("Assets/facebook-logo.png"), height: 35.0),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                      child: Text(
                        'Sign in with Google',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          color: Colors.grey,
```

here's the screen shot of how many buttons are arranged i want to have all the buttons constant and texts inside it formatted properly:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the column I think. So, I removed that. Here is the way you can create custom button with size. Feel free to change **minWidth** to get the best result.

**new:** Please consider using **Flexible** and **Expanded** inside the row. If the button text goes in multi-line please reduce the font size to fix it.

```
     Widget _signInButton() {
    return ButtonTheme(
      minWidth: 400.0,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: OutlineButton(
          splashColor: Colors.grey,
          onPressed: () {},
          shape:
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)),
          highlightElevation: 0,
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),

             child:   Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Flexible(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: Image.network(
                          'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                          height: 35,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child:  Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                            child: Text('Sign in with Facebook',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey))),
                      )

                    ])
              ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: You also don't need  the container as well as the Column.

Comment: so should i remove the column as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204815/discussion-between-amon-chowdhury-and-myname).

Comment: can you also tell me how can i arrrange the text and icon inside properly

Comment: you can also use only the vertical padding to get more room for the button text. Or it could go in multi-line.